# How to define range of rows in excel while using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using a simple Euclidian distance formula `sqrt((a-b)^2 + (c-d)^2)` and I have more than 60,000 data in my each excel sheet. Instead of dragging mouse (which is very inconvenient for this large number of data) how can I define the range of records? For example my formula looks like -

```
=SQRT((H2-J2)^2+(I2-K2)^2)
```

And also, to popolate the result in 60000 rows, where should I write the formula?

Comment: You can use copy paste instead of dragging.

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about.. I assume i have to copy the formula but where should I paste?

Comment: Enter the first formula and select that cell, then double-click the little box in the bottom-right corner of that cell. That will fill down the formula as far as there is something in the cell to the left of the formula cell.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer (as such). To avoid the issue that double-clicking only fills down as far as one row short of the first empty cell in the column immediately to the left:

1. Home > Editing - Find & Select, Go To, enter `B60000` as Reference, OK.
2. Enter something ('z' will do).
3. Return to topmost cell containing the desired formula, copy it, select the cell immediately below it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and Paste.